# python html extract tags

Tags: python, html

How would it be possible to do the following:

1. Scan through an html page (preferably through a whole domain (www.python.org) and extract all

h1 h2 ...hn Tags

and write all Headings to a file. In the correct order:

Start with h1
Than h2

until we reach the next h1

Comment: This is a seriously incomplete question. I can't make head nor tail of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the requirement to scan a whole website, you might want to look into [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) to grab the files to scrape. Be careful not to hit the site with the equivalent of a DoS attack though.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Nice, very interesting! How can I avoid being seen as a potential threat?

Comment: Just limit how hard and often you hit the site. Of course, if you control the site just pick a quiet moment and hammer it for a while.

There aren't any hard or fast guidelines: what a site can cope with/is considered acceptable will vary enormously.

Answer (score 2):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [PyQuery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery).